# How does the Google adsense works?

Tags: adsense

can you tell me, how does the Google Ad sense works?

please explain  me in brief..

Comment: It's somewhat complicated, but ... uh ... did you try "how does google adsense work"? First result looks reasonably readable: http://hubpages.com/hub/How_does_Google_Adsense_work

Comment: I want to know the google calculations. if u know tell me

Comment: this is going to be a well guarded secret, simply because the more you know about hte process the less money they make. In simple terms, they ensure they maximize the amount of revenue per key word by ensuring a blind auction keeps the price 'competitive'

Comment: @steve do they give money on d basis of impression?

Answer (score 1):

There's [quite a bit of information](http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=29574) available from Google on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to "use" it? or its algorithms? For the first one, they have a page for that, for the later one, I don't think you will even be able to figure it out:)

Answer (score 0):

You place a javascript code in your site, and whenever someone visits your site, Google puts an ad in place. If the user clicks the add, you get money for it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is orientated around Google's contextual targeting.

In brief: Google sends a bot to read each page of your website. It looks at all the terms on the page and discards common words and instead tries to understand themes. Google also looks at adgroups of AdWords advertisers and looks to build an understanding of the themes of the keywords. Another algorithm pairs the two together so that relevant ads appear on a webpage.